# Upload a file to S3 using the AWS SDK

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, libgdx

I'm trying to upload a file to an Amazon S3 bucket using the AWS SDK.

```
class LogToS3Bucket extends Thread{

    public void run() {
        super.run();
        Gdx.app.log("msg", "secondThreadRunning yeahhhhh!");
        File fileToPut = new File("../../../MyProject", "settings.txt");
        String accessKey = "<accessKey>";
        String secretKey = "<secretKey>";
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
        AmazonS3 conn = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

        conn.putObject("bucketname", "filename.txt", fileToPut);
    }

}
```

It doesn't work though, it throws an error on the call to .putObject()

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Error Code: BadDigest, AWS Error Message: The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received.
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:614)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:312)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:165)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2951)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1123)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:979)
    at com.myproject.LogToS3Bucket.run(LogToS3Bucket.java:22)
```

Comment: did you tried with the sample which they have provided with AWS android sdk ?

Comment: Yeah that is the example code. It doesn't work from my phone though. I think you have to use the android sdk for an android device. It's a little annoying because I need a cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out I think-- since my application is constantly editing that file and this snippet happens in a separate thread, the file is actually changed before it gets uploaded... If I make a temporary copy of the file and upload that to the bucket, it works.

Comment: temporary copy?? can u please explain a bit more?

Comment: Make a deep copy of the file (take a snapshot of the file data either in memory or by making a copy on the filesystem) so you don't write to it mid-upload. You could alternatively use some locking mechanism to keep uploading and file-writing separate.